# LaTeX scaling tikzpicture does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

The TikZ picture in the following code does not scale correctly. It overlaps with text. If I comment out `transform canvas={scale=0.5}` then it works correctly (but I would like to scale everything).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,matrix,shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
  >=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=8em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=7em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=7em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  node/.style={scale=0.45},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=4pt},
}



\newcommand\schema{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below,transform canvas={scale=0.5}]
  %\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below]
    \node (preprocessing) [punktchain ]  {text text};

    \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
      every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
      \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
      (landmarks) {
        \begin{tabular}{l}
          text \\
          text \\ 
        \end{tabular}
      };
    \end{scope}

    \node[punktchain, join,] (potentialfunction) {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\ 
      \end{tabular}
    };
    \node[punktchain, join,] (query) {text};
    \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
      every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
      \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
      (input) {
        text };
    \end{scope}

    \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(preprocessing.north), \p2=(preprocessing.south) in
    ($(1.5, \y1)$) -- ($(1.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(potentialfunction.north), \p2=(query.south) in
    ($(1.5, \y1)$) -- ($(1.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\ 
      \end{tabular}
    };    
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \centering
  \subfloat[1 ] {  \schema }
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \subfloat[2 ] {  \schema }

  \caption{Comparison }  


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`transform canvas` should usually be the last resort: It makes TikZ lose track of the node positions, so can cause more harm than good.

In your case, a simple `scale=0.5` works if you make the nodes scalable as well. By default, TikZ assumes that you don't want to scale nodes, because this will change the text size. You can change this behaviour for a `tikzpicture` by adding `every node/.append style={transform shape}`:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `\scalebox{0.5}{ \schema }`:

[image]

---

*Code for first example*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,matrix,shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
  >=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=8em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=7em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=7em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  node/.style={scale=0.45},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=4pt},
}



\newcommand\schema{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below,
  scale=0.5, every node/.append style={transform shape}]
  %\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below]
    \node (preprocessing) [punktchain ]  {text text};

    \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
      every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
      \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
      (landmarks) {
        \begin{tabular}{l}
          text \\
          text \\ 
        \end{tabular}
      };
    \end{scope}

    \node[punktchain, join,] (potentialfunction) {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\ 
      \end{tabular}
    };
    \node[punktchain, join,] (query) {text};
    \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
      every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
      \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
      (input) {
        text };
    \end{scope}

    \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(preprocessing.north), \p2=(preprocessing.south) in
    ($(1.5, \y1)$) -- ($(1.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(potentialfunction.north), \p2=(query.south) in
    ($(1.5, \y1)$) -- ($(1.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\ 
      \end{tabular}
    };    
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \centering
  \subfloat[1 ] {  \schema }
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \subfloat[2 ] {  \schema }

  \caption{Comparison }  


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

*Code for second example*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
  decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,matrix,shapes.symbols}

\tikzset{
  >=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners, 
    % fill=black!10,
    draw=black, very thick,
    text width=8em, 
    minimum height=3em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
    tape,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
    minimum width=7em,
    draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
    text width=7em, 
    minimum height=3.5em, 
    text centered, 
    on chain},
  every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
  decoration={brace},
  tuborg/.style={decorate},
  node/.style={scale=0.45},
  tubnode/.style={midway, right=4pt},
}



\newcommand\schema{

  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below]
  %\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below]
    \node (preprocessing) [punktchain ]  {text text};

    \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
      every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
      \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
      (landmarks) {
        \begin{tabular}{l}
          text \\
          text \\ 
        \end{tabular}
      };
    \end{scope}

    \node[punktchain, join,] (potentialfunction) {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\ 
      \end{tabular}
    };
    \node[punktchain, join,] (query) {text};
    \begin{scope}[start branch=venstre,
      every join/.style={->, thick, shorten <=1pt}, ]
      \node[punktchain, on chain=going left, join=by {<-}]
      (input) {
        text };
    \end{scope}

    \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(preprocessing.north), \p2=(preprocessing.south) in
    ($(1.5, \y1)$) -- ($(1.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\
      \end{tabular}
    };

    \draw[tuborg, decoration={brace}] let \p1=(potentialfunction.north), \p2=(query.south) in
    ($(1.5, \y1)$) -- ($(1.5, \y2)$) node[tubnode] {
      \begin{tabular}{l}
        text \\
        text \\ 
      \end{tabular}
    };    
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

  \centering
  \subfloat[1 ] {  \scalebox{0.5}{\schema} }
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \subfloat[2 ] {  \scalebox{0.5}{\schema} }

  \caption{Comparison }  


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have one question for the scaling of `node`. I understand the idea that nodes can come with texts, so it is better not to scale them unless otherwise specified. However in my humble opinion, the separations among nodes should be scaled. But by default, the separations remain intact (for `tikz-feynman` at least), why is it implemented this way? Thanks!